# JSON syntax error in IE8?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, flask

I have a site that otherwise works well in most browsers and I started off having errors in IE8 Saying JSON is undefined. Internets told me to drop in json2.js and things would be fine.

Now it gives this error:

"Syntax error" line 204 character 7"

Here is line 204:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
```

I've tried these things:

```
1. <!DOCTYPE html>
2. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
3. <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.min.js"></script>
```

The JSON I verified is valid JSON and I'm out of ideas. Where should I look next?

**EDIT 2:**

It'll be easier if I just post the link temporarily: http://pilot032013.herokuapp.com/address/51376f833ef9eb361f354ebc/

**Edit 1:**

```
function getUncuratedBuildingSuccess(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  //console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
  var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
  CURRENT_BUILDING_ID = data.id;
  //Load Images
  generateImageUrls(data.id);

  //Some point soon, I want to have a building object reflect the database
  building_footprint = fixBrokenFootprint(data.points);
  var building = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: building_footprint,
      strokeColor: "#6f298b",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#ad2390",
      fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  extendBounds(building);

  building_location = new google.maps.LatLng(data.center[1], data.center[0]);
  building.setMap(map);
  displayAddress(data.dte_addresses);
  displayGSVImage(data.dte_addresses);
  displayParcel(data.parcel_id);
  displayStatus(replaceAmbig(data.override));
  //displayPastVotes(data.id);
}
```

Here's the JSON held in jqXHR.responseText:

```
{"suffix": "", "owner_mail_state": "None", "parcel_id": "4562354", "street_name": "", "owner_mail_zipcode": "None", "living_area": "None", "imaging_runs": ["20130307_004341_4"], "owner": "None", "num_floors": null, "id": "51424ad73ee3eb75fc5deae1", "city": "Boston", "owner_mail_address": "None", "energy_score_raw": "24.5240226853", "structural_class": "None", "zipcode": "49525", "state": "MI", "override": "None", "assessor_lot": "None", "street_num": "", "owner_mail_city": "None", "geocoded_address": [], "unit_num": "None", "use_description": "None", "vertical_panoramas": [["20130307_004341_4_r_1482539_mts", "20130307_004341_4_r_1482524_mts", "20130307_004341_4_r_1482555_mts", "20130307_004341_4_r_1482570_mts"]], "building_style": "None", "assessor_map": "None", "exterior_material": "None", "fireplace": "None", "roof_type": "None", "use_code": "None", "year_built": "None", "center": [-85.6279876548728, 43.028673273958084], "energy_score_city": 69, "year_remodeled": "None", "air_conditioner": "None", "created_at": "2013-06-11T15:20:12.301190", "heat_type": "None", "owner_occupied": "None", "contract": "dte", "energy_score_neighbors": 79, "points": [[-85.6279345148065, 43.0287278589084], [-85.62793027273129, 43.0286178277214], [-85.6280408213034, 43.0286193662203], [-85.6280455189338, 43.0287278763051], [-85.6279345148065, 43.0287278589084]], "num_units": "None", "yme_addresses": [{"_changed_fields": [], "site_id": "3390379", "_initialised": true, "_created": false, "_data": {"city": "Boston", "suffix": "ROAD NE", "state": "MA", "street_name": "4 MILE", "is_contracted": null, "zipcode": "49525", "prefix": null, "street_num": "1665"}, "ser_seq": "1"}], "_id": "None", "gross_area": "None"}
```

Comment: Give your data response. We will have idea if you give us data of ajax request

Comment: Trying your link I get a javascript error at loading time inside the json3 library when in IE8 mode. This seems to be this bug: https://github.com/bestiejs/json3/issues/35 which is apparently solved when using the non-minified version or the 3.2.5. branch. Not sure if this is the whole issue or there is something else. Note that IE8 _in standards mode_ doesn't need a JSON polyfill, it should work out of the box.

Comment: Error in given link:  "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined 
json3.min.js, line 13 character 93". Moreover it has referenced json3 not json2 as stated by you above.

Comment: Woops, I forgot to push the changes. I debugged that already. I'm relaunching the heroku app now. Edit: It's no relaunched. Please take another look if you're still around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could get this type of errors in case the url of a

```
 <script src="...url..."></script>
```

does not return javascript

Answer (score 0):

Script note found on your link.

```
GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.5/json3.min.js 404 (Not Found) pilot032013.herokuapp.com:31
```

Check your JavaScript CDN again make sure it work properly.

Comment: Checked and fixed. Now I have a new error with length is undefined. I'm guessing this is a script error.

Comment: Please comment console.log() on IE8. It don't know console